# Logical/physical implementation plan difference between df.count() and df.show()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For the same dataframe, `df.count()` takes 1/10th of the time compared to `df.show()`. I am curious what is the difference in the implementation plan between these two actions.

Comment: I can easily imagine that `count()` can freely skip some transformation except the ones that can affect it (like filter). A smart implementation of any transformation pipeline would probably have optimizations like this.

Comment: Are you simply reading your dataframe from a file or table? What is the format?